# Is pop eip legal instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I’m working on this theoretical test I got at university, and have been asked this question :
After some instruction, esp grew by 4 and eip grew by 20, what can possibly be the instruction?
I marked both “pop eip” and “ret”.
Is it possible in nasm 32 bit assembly to execute pop eip instruction?

Comment: In 32-bit code EIP is not a register you can address directly, thus there is no POP EIP. There are instructions that can modify EIP as a side effect. RET, IRET, CALL, JMP etc. An instruction that adds 4 to ESP and changes EIP would be RET.

Comment: Interesting to know: Early x86 CPUs (8086, 8088) actually had a `pop cs` instruction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`pop eip` is not a real x86 instruction.**  No assembler will assemble it, AFAIK.

It's pseudocode for *explaining* what `ret` does. See the Operation section [in the manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret).  Specifically a normal "near" `ret`; far jmp/call/ret are basically unused in "normal" 32-bit code.

`ret` has its own opcode separate from any of the encodings for `pop`, and x86 also chooses to give it a separate mnemonic.  It would have been a valid design for `pop eip` to also be accepted as another name for the `0xc3` opcode.  x86 does have the `mov` mnemonic overloaded for many different opcodes, including `mov` to/from [control registers](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1), `mov` to/from [debug registers](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV-2.html), as well as the [standard `mov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) between integer registers and/or memory or immediate.  (That "standard" form of `mov` also has several different opcodes to choose from, though.)

But that would have been a bit weird because `push eip` doesn't exist except as `call +0` which has the performance side-effect of being a jump.

EIP is not one of the 8 general-purpose integer registers, so the normal encodings of `pop` can't encode a `ret`.  That's one reason why `ret` needs its own opcode, and why it makes sense for it to have a separate mnemonic in asm source.  x86 instructions encode registers as 3-bit numbers, or optionally 4-bit on x86-64.  Or as an *implicit* source or destination, like EDX:EAX for `mul` or `div`, or `pushf` implicitly reads EFLAGS: it's just implied by that opcode without any bits that specifically *mean* EFLAGS.

---

`ret` isn't magic: all it does is pop the stack and use the result as a jump target.  It's up to the programmer to make sure ESP is pointing at an address you want to jump to, typically a return address.

Some beginners fail to understand this and think that `ret` will magically return to the last `call`, so they don't make the connection between faulting on `ret` and their code messing up the stack.

I've definitely written something like "**`ret` is the name we use on x86 for `pop eip`**" in SO answers and comments many times.

Fun fact: on ARM 32-bit, the program counter *is* one of the 16 integer registers, `r15`, so you really can `pop {r4, pc}` to restore a saved R4 and pop a saved `lr` (link register = return address) into the program counter all in one instruction.   So ARM literally can do the equivalent of `pop eip` with the same opcode it uses for popping general-purpose integer registers.

---

> esp grew by 4 and eip grew by 20

Yes, I think [C3 `ret` or C2 00 00 `ret 0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) are the only 2 opcodes that could do this, and both use the `ret` mnemonic.

If EIP grew by 15 or fewer, a long encoding of `add esp, 4` or `pop eax` could account for it, e.g. with multiple redundant `rep` and/or `fs` prefixes and an `imm32` encoding for the immediate `4`.

x86 instructions can be at most 15 bytes long; if decoding doesn't reach the end of an instruction before 15 bytes, the CPU takes a `#UD` exception, just like for other illegal instructions.  So changing EIP by 20 bytes with one instruction is only possible with a jump.  And the only jump that *increases* ESP is `ret`; jmp / jcc leave it unmodified, `call` pushes a return address.

`iret` is almost possible but it pops `CS:IP`, a FLAGS value, and a new `SS:SP`: You can't get it to pop just 4 bytes.  (Especially in 32-bit mode.)

`sysret` doesn't modify ESP, and is only usable by the kernel (ring 0).  [`sysexit`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysexit) sets RSP from RCX and RIP = RDX, but I'm pretty sure that's not an answer they were looking for. :P

16-bit `retf` could work in a very specific case: if EIP was in the low 16 bits of 32-bit address-space, and the current CS value was already on the stack.  16-bit jumps, including `retf`, truncate EIP to IP.

I'm not 100% sure a `66h` operand-size override prefix for `retf` in 32-bit mode will get it to only pop 4 bytes not 6; the pseudocode in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret says:

```
   // retf in protected mode, not vm86, RETURN-TO-SAME-PRIVILEGE-LEVEL:
            ELSE (* OperandSize = 16 *)
                    EIP := Pop();
                    EIP := EIP AND 0000FFFFH;
                    CS := Pop(); (* 16-bit pop *)
```

That first Pop() is being assigned to a 32-bit register; does that make it a 32-bit pop?  But this part of the pseudo-code would apply even in 16-bit protected mode.

Comment: Why not 16bit RETF?

Comment: @l4m2: Interesting, yes that could pop 4 bytes, but it would truncate EIP to IP as well as popping a new CS.  If EIP happened to already be in the low 16 bits of 32-bit address-space, and the current CS value was already on the stack, then yes it'd be possible.  "EIP grew by 20" kind of implies that EIP is a normal 32-bit address.

Comment: To avoid rewriting CS, `16bit ret 2` is also good. `eip` still need to be low

Comment: @l4m2: Does `66h retf` only pop 4 bytes in 32-bit mode?  Intel's pseudocode isn't specific about size for that case.  As for `66h ret 2`, yeah that's a fun one.  I did already mention both `C2` and `C3` near-ret opcodes without the operand-size prefix.

Comment: I tried on DEBUG16, and `66 ret` pop 4 bytes, `66 retf` pop 8 bytes

Comment: `bit16 ret -64` allows modifying `ip` and `sp` to anywhere, but `ret -64` no longer exist in 32-bit as it's unsigned extended