# There is a problem with "push" instruction [Access violation]

Tags: assembly, x86

What's wrong with that simple code, I don't know what's happened, the `push eax` instruction occurs that error:

[image]

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

.data

.code       
_start:
    mov eax, 100
    push eax
    ret
end _start
```

Comment: `ret` pops a value from the stack and jumps to that address - in this case 100 or 0x64 which doesn't contain executable code.

Comment: Also related: [Is pop eip legal instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56676840) = it's what `ret` is equivalent to.